# Uniform convergence of the series of derivatives of Weierstrass function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to establish convergence/divergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(ab)^n \pi \sin(b^n \pi x)$, where $ab > 1$, $0 < a <1$ and $b$ is odd natural number. 
What test can I use for proving that this series diverge?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the series converges then: 
$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (ab)^n\pi\sin(b^n\pi x) = 0$

Comment: Thank you! Thought about it also.